# Issues with settimeout and scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, settimeout

I'm somewhat new to the world of coding, and  I have (possibly foolishly) decided that I would like to make my friend a Choose Your Own Adventure Game game for a birthday present. In short, I've run into a problem where a time delay is needed to give the user time to read the text and also to scroll down the page, because the window does not scroll otherwise. I ended up trying to use .settimeout() to create set delay, but the problem is that the code after the settimeout itself runs while this is happening, causing a dead end of sorts for the user. It  looks like this:

```
  //A bunch of text and story up here 

  window.setTimeout( function () { 'prompt to get variable for if statement' }, delay );

  if(true)
    { //code to run}
  else
   {//code to run}
```

This is followed by several other prompts and their corresponding if/else statements.

I'm assuming that the code is running while the delay is happening, and I was wondering if a better methods of doing this exists. I know that there is no pause function in Javascript, but I figure there must be some way to allow the user to scroll down before another prompt pops up. Thank you.

Comment: setTimeout schedules (a) call(s) to happen "at some point in the future". It's not a function that makes your JavaScript wait, it does the exact opposite, letting your JavaScript immediately continue irrespective of the timeout code running. In fact, your next lines are guaranteed to not be able to rely on the code in the timeout having run because it won't have yet, the earliest it can run is when the code it's scheduled in finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The if-else statement is going to run straight away. You should put it in your setTimeout function, like so:

```
//A bunch of text and story up here 

window.setTimeout( function () {
  //do some magic



  if(true)
    { //code to run}
  else
   {//code to run}
}, delay );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var donext = false;
window.setTimeout( function() {
  donext = true;
}, delay);

if(donext)
{ //code to run}
else
{ //code to run}
```